# Conditional Expectation vs Conditional Probability Markov Process

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

For my stochastic process class, we have many definitions of a Markov Process.  One of them is the following:

$P(X_{t+1} \in A | \sigma(X_1, ...,X_t)) = P(X_{t+1} \in A | \sigma(X_t))$.

(A measurable)

I have seen it stated that this is equivalent to

$E(f(X_{t+1}) | \sigma(X_1, ...,X_t)) = E(f(X_{t+1}) | \sigma(X_t))$.

for bounded, measurable f

I am having trouble seeing why this equivalence is true.  Could someone shed some light on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Formally you would need the set $A$ to be Borel measurable. Equivalence means an "if and only if" statement, one direction of which is easier than the other.  Can you prove either direction?

Comment: I added that A is measurable.  If $X_n$ is real-valued than the <= direction is trivial but I am not certain if it is not real-valued

Comment: Follow-up:  If $X_n$ is real-valued, I assume that it is not necessarily true that $E(X_{t+1} | \sigma(X_1, ...,X_t)) = E(X_{t+1} | \sigma(X_t))$ as the identity map is not bounded.

Comment: I was assuming that $X_n$ is a random variable, but, regardless, as long as $\{X_{t+1} \in A\}$ is in the sigma algebra, you can represent the probability of that event as an expectation of a bounded and measurable function, so the $\impliedby$ direction is essentially the same as the random-variable case. Do you agree?

Comment: One pesky problem: If you are not using random variables with the Borel sigma-algebra, it is not clear to me what is meant by a "measurable function $f$" because you seem to be evaluating $f$ at different "random objects" $f(X_1)$, $f(X_2)$.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear.  I was assuming that $X_t$ was taking values in some measurable space (S, $\mathcal{S}$). and f mapped S to the reals with the Borel sigma-algebra

I do agree---that was obvious, I just wasn't thinking.  Again, to clarify if $X_t$ is real-valued than it is not necessarily true that the two conditional expectations are equal as the identity map is not bounded.

Comment: The above statements (in your question about indicator functions and bounded functions) do not have much to do with concluding things about $E[X_t]$ or $E[X_t|F_t]$ for some sigma algebra $F_t$. For example we might have $\{X_t\}_{t=0}^{\infty}$ i.i.d. (which is trivially a Markov process) such that $E[X_t]$ does not exist. For example $X_t$ might have the Cauchy distribution. Nevertheless we can speak of $E[f(X_t)]$ for bounded (and measurable) functions $f$.

Comment: What if $E[X_t]$ did exist?  I assume it is still not necessarily true that $E(X_{t+1} | \sigma(X_1,...,X_t)) = E(X_{t+1} | \sigma(X_t))$ a.s.
The above would be true in your iid example.

Comment: Temporarily restricting to nonnegative random variables $X_t\geq 0$,  you could say for all $M>0$ that $$0\leq X_t1_{\{0\leq X_t\leq M\}} \leq X_t$$ and $x1_{\{0\leq x \leq M\}}$ is a bounded and measurable function.  Also, $X_t1_{\{X_t\leq M\}} \nearrow X_t$ (as $M\nearrow \infty$).

Comment: So you can apply conditional monotone convergence to both sides.  Then you do in fact get that
$E(X_{t+1} | \sigma(X_1, ...,X_t)) = E(X_{t+1} | \sigma(X_t))$?
for $X_t$ non-negative.  But what about $X_t$ generally.

Comment: Well you could write $X = X^+ - X^-$ if you want, or perhaps there is some conditional form of Lebesgue dominated convergence with $|X1_{\{|X|\leq M\}}| \leq |X|$ for all $M\in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first equation follows from the second by taking $f=I_A$.

If the first equation holds then the second one holds for $f$ of the form $f=I_A$ with $A$ measurable. Hence it holds for all simple functions $f$. Any bounded measurable function is a uniform limit of simple functions. Also Bounded Convergence Theorem holds for conditional expectations. Hence the second equation holds for all bounded measurable functions $f$.

Comment: Good points---I should have remembered my measure theory